# Example Alloy Android app with a webview that loads local html and javascript?

Tags: android, titanium, android-webview

I'm looking for an example Alloy app that shows a Webview on Android that loads a local HTML file with <script> tag that successfully loads a local Javascript file.

I am using Titanium SDK 3.0.2.GA and compiling for Android 2.2 (emulator). I have an example app that should be easy to fix, if someone knows what the issue is:

https://github.com/jbeuckm/AndroidJsFileTest

Comment: why is this any different in alloy then regular titanium?

Comment: @Aaron, it shouldn't be different, but I have now spent a couple evening putting js/jsf files in different places and haven't been able to get them to load :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't take much effort.

**insideAssetsFolder.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Whatever</title>
     <script src="insideAssetsFolder.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    // Blah
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="container">
        <WebView id="content" url="/insideAssetsFolder.html" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**insideAssetsFolder.js**

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    alert('Window now presentable');
};
```

Thats pretty much all you need coming from a blank alloy project. You may need to rename `insideAssetsFolder.js` extension since Alloy (sometimes) will not build it into the final app.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that but the JS doesn't run when I use that code. Here is a test app: https://github.com/jbeuckm/AndroidJsFileTest

Comment: You cant execute JS till the HTML document has been loaded. Try inserting the `<script src="/insideAssetsFolder.js"></script>` inside the <body> tag.

Comment: That's crazy talk :) But I tried it anyway = no dice. Does that work for you? Is this an Android-browser specific thing?

Comment: Try instead to use the `window.onload` event like this (replace /test.wvjs with this)`window.onload = function(e){ alert('assets/test.wvjs'); }` Or, just use jQuery.

Comment: A simple javascript alert will work at any time it is read by the browser. onload or jquery ready events are to prevent references to elements which haven't loaded yet.

Comment: In your posted test.html code I changed this: `<script src="/test.wvjs"></script>` to this `<script src="test.wvjs"></script>` and it worked in both the iOS sim, and on a Nexus 4 device.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I really thought I had tried that same idea but it works now. You do not need to use window.onload

Comment: Well, if you do anything that's not using alerts, `window.onload` or something similar would be a good idea I think :-) Glad it's working.

Comment: I agree: the actual project uses jquery/document-ready but for a quick js path test, a naked alert suffices. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try renaming the extension of assets/test.js.  From what my experience, since Titanium compiles .js files, that can create conflicts. It helps when calling a javascript file from a webview to use an alternate file extension like .wvjs.  You can really use whatever extension, I just prefer wvjs as it helps me to recognize that its javascript i'm including specifically for WebView use.

Comment: I updated the example changing .js to .wvjs but I don't get the alert. Does this work for you? https://github.com/jbeuckm/AndroidJsFileTest/tree/master/app/assets